# Why my textarea shrinks and when i refresh the page it goes to normal again

Tags: html, css, angular-material

Why is my textarea shrinking automatically when i open the page.
[image: It looks like this]

And when i refresh the page it goes to normal again. What may be the issue
[image: normal]

And this is my html code

```
<div class="col-md-12 input-group pab pcomment">
        <div class="input-group-prepend">
          <span class="input-group-text">Comment</span>
        </div>
        <textarea matinput formControlName="pastMedicalHistoryComment" class="form-control" aria-label="Comment"></textarea>
    </div>
```

And this my formcontroll css

```
.input-group>.custom-file, .input-group>.custom-select, .input-group>.form-control {
    position: relative;
    -ms-flex: 1 1 auto;
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    width: 1%;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: Maybe I missed something, but that's what `width: 1%;` does. What do you want to achieve with this setting?

Comment: above css is from the bootstrap not a custom css. But when i overide that width : 1% textarea moves down and the comment box stays above the textarea

Answer (score 0):

just give it some `min-width:400px` or some pixels that you want to give default minimum width.

```css
.input-group>.custom-file, .input-group>.custom-select, .input-group>.form-control {
    position: relative;
    -ms-flex: 1 1 auto;
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    width: 1%;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    min-width:400px;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-12 input-group pab pcomment">
        <div class="input-group-prepend">
          <span class="input-group-text">Comment</span>
        </div>
        <textarea matinput formControlName="pastMedicalHistoryComment" class="form-control" aria-label="Comment"></textarea>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You essentially want this, but I'll let you incorporate it with BS:

```css
div {
  display: flex; 
  align-items: center;
}
label {
  padding: 10px;
  width: max-content;
  background: #f7f7f7;
}
textarea {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <label>Comment</label>
  <textarea></textarea>
</div>
```